# Objective C: defining variables within block

Tags: asynchronous, scope, objective-c-blocks

I have an objective C function that looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)logInUser:(NSString*)user password:(NSString*)pass
{
__block BOOL ret;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/login", kBaseUrl]]];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"username":user, @"password":pass };
request.HTTPBody = [[self urlEncodedStringFromDict:dict] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


[[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if (error == nil) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        NSLog(@"logIn statuscode=%ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
        ret = YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"logIn error=%@", error);
        ret = NO;
    }
}] resume];

return ret;
}
```

where session is defined in the header. I'm trying to change the value of ret within the block, as I have the __block identifier in the declaration, but it is not retaining the value outside of the block, I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that I'm passing the block as a parameter, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the block can change the value of a `__block` variable, and the change is seen "outside of the block". You are confused because you don't see the change when you return `ret` from your function, but that's just because the block hasn't run at that point yet, because it's run asynchronously.

Comment: oh i see, the value is being changed after the return statement. How do I get information out of the block statement before the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

For your task you cannot return result synchronously, because internet requests always require time to get back with response. So you should change signature and body of **logInUser** method slightly. It could be:

```
- (void)logInUser:(NSString *)user
         password:(NSString *)pass
       completion:(void (^)(BOOL isSuccess))completion
{
    // ...
    [[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // ...
        if (completion) {
            completion(YES);  // or NO - depends on code above
        }
    }] resume];
}
```

Usage:

```
- (IBAction)loginDidPress
{
    // TODO: show activity indicator

    UserManager *userManager = [UserManager new];
    [userManager logInUser:self.userTextField.text
                  password:self.passwordTextField.text
                completion:^(BOOL isSuccess) {
        // TODO: hide activity indicator
        // TODO: implement further logic based on result
    }];
}
```

This way of implementation async functions is most popular nowadays. But also you could use delegation pattern and notifications.